# "Uncaught TypeError: that.getAttribute is not a function" in successive recursion after working on initial call

Tags: javascript, recursion, this

i'm trying to start moving an object on my screen when the user clicks on it and stop it from moving when the cursor leaves.

```
  var sphere = d3.select('.sphere');
  var trigger = 1;
  var speed = 0.5;
  sphere.on('click', click);
  sphere.on('mouseenter', mouseenter);
  sphere.on('mouseleave',mouseleave);

  function mouseenter(){
    console.log("Mouse Enter" + trigger)
    trigger = 1;
  }

  function mouseleave(){
    console.log("Mouse leave" + trigger)
    trigger = 0;
  }

  function click(){
    console.log("Mouse click" + trigger)
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("MOVE");
      var currentPosition = that.getAttribute('position');
      var sphere = d3.select(that);
      console.log(currentPosition);
      currentPosition["z"] -= speed;
      console.log(currentPosition);
      sphere.attr('position', currentPosition);
      if(trigger){
        click();
      }
    }, 1000)
  }
```

Result

```
retry.html:41 Mouse click1
retry.html:44 MOVE
retry.html:47 {x: 0, y: 2.25, z: -1.5}
retry.html:49 {x: 0, y: 2.25, z: -2}
retry.html:41 Mouse click1
retry.html:44 MOVE
retry.html:45 Uncaught TypeError: that.getAttribute is not a function at retry.html:45
```

i expected it to keep executing it till mouseleave() executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Function.protytype.call` to explicitly define context to function exection:

```
if(trigger){
  click.call(that)
}
```